# iOS ARC complete?

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

A former developer built a well-written iPhone app for our organization. After he quit, another developer updated the app for Automatic Reference Counting (ARC). This developer is no longer here. I don't trust what he did as he was an unscrupulous developer. I have 15 years of development experience, but I am new to iPhone development. I need to know if I should leave his changes intact. I have carefully compared the changes he made. He only took out the dealloc functions and removed use of 'release', 'retain', and 'autorelease'. From what I've read http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html:

You cannot explicitly invoke dealloc, or implement or invoke retain, release, retainCount, or autorelease.

This should be ok.

However, this article

http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2011/11/everything-know-about-arc/

mentions

With LLVM 3.0 selected as compiler the Build Setting Objective-C Automatic Reference Counting can be set to YES.

This setting is still set to NO. It seems to me that the code was updated to use ARC but the project is not configured for ARC. Can you please tell me how to continue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, that parameter has to be set to YES, probably the code is leaking everywhere.

You can check if the project is leaking using the Analyzer (Product -> Analyze).

If ARC is disabled and the releases are removed from the code, the analyzer will inform you that your code is leaking, and where.

So, after enabling ARC, the analyzer wont give you any leaks.

Another way of checking if ARC is disabled or enabled is using release or autorelease in your code. If ARC is enabled, you should see a warning or an error.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I used the Analyzer and it found 72 issues. I changed the ARC setting to YES and re-ran the Analyzer. It found 1 issue/warning. Am I safe to submit the app to the app store after resolving this issue?

Comment: This seems now to be the correct setting. But after 15 years of SW experience you should know that nobody can answer, if you are safe to submit the app.

Comment: Well, if you analyze and build and there's no warnings... it means that everything seems ok. If you want to be sure, use the tools to profile the app, but in theory should be "ready"

Comment: @AntonioMG It only means that the analyzer can't find any issues.  The app may be leaking tons of memory from retain cycles or it might be crashy as heck because behavior has changed.  An app is only ready to submit to the app store when it has been properly tested (where "properly tested" is an exercise whose definition is left to the reader).

Comment: That´s what I meant with use the tools

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I will only submit the app after testing has been successfully performed. I was asking more if the ARC change could be considered complete at this point. Thanks again for your insight.

Comment: @lilmmd See my answer. To be complete, you may need to consider weak references.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned [LLVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LLVM) 3.0. That means you may be deploying your app to iOS 4. If so, beware that ARC has a limitation in iOS 4, known as "[ARClite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_Reference_Counting#Zeroing_Weak_References)": Weak references are *not* automatically zeroed out (nil'd out). You need to nil them explicitly in your code. In practice, this means nil'ing out outlets.

Apple document: [Objective-C Feature Availability Index](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ObjCAvailabilityIndex/index.html)